# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key with multiple outputs

Tags: python, excel, regex, pandas

I am extracting a substring from an Excel cell and the entire string says this:

```
The bolts are 5" long each and 3" apart
```

I want to extract the length of the bolt which is `5"`. And I use the following code to get that

```
df['Bolt_Length'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'(\s[0-9]")',expand=False)
```

But if the string says the following:

```
The bolts are 10" long each and 3" apart
```

and I try to use to the following code:

```
df['Bolt_Length'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'(\s(\d{1,2})")',expand=False)
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I think Python doesn't know which number to acquire. The `10"` or `3"`

How can I fix this? How do I tell Python to only go for the first `"`?

On another note what if I want to get both the bolt length and distance from another bolt? How do I extract the two at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have two capture groups in your second regular expression `(\s(\d{1,2})")`, not one. So basically, you're telling Python to get the number *with* the `"`, *and* the same number *without* the `"`:

```
>>> df['Description'].str.extract(r'(\s(\d{1,2})")', expand=False)
      0   1
0    5"   5
1   10"  10
```

You can add `?:` right after the opening parenthesis of a group to make it so that it does not capture anything, though it still functions as a group. The following makes it so that the inner group, which excludes the `"`, does not capture:

```
#                                notice vv
>>> df['Description'].str.extract(r'(\s(?:\d{1,2})")', expand=False)
0      5"
1     10"
Name: Description, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because your regex contains *two* capturing groups, that extract *two* column values, BUT you assign those to a *single* column, `df['Bolt_Length']`.

**You need to use as many capturing groups in the regex pattern as there are columns you assign the values to**:

```py
df['Bolt_Length'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'\s(\d{1,2})"',expand=False)
```

The `\s(\d{1,2})"` regex only contains one pair of unescaped parentheses that form a capturing group, so this works fine since this single value is assigned to a single `Bolt_Length` column.